# ANN training progress resets every new training session using FANN

Tags: c++, fann

I have a standard neural network which I have trained for some time, but not until perfection. After the training session is complete, I save the network on disk.

After some time I want to resume training the network from where it left. The problem is, it seems that every time I start a new training session, the weights and biases seem to be totally reset, which means I'm training the network from scratch all over again:

Previous session:

[image]

New session:

[image]

Here is the excerpt from my training function:

```
void trainNet(fann *net) {
    const unsigned int
        max_epochs = 1000,
        epochs_between_reports = 10;
    const float desired_error = 0.01f;
    net -> learning_momentum = 0.1f;
    fann_train_on_file(net, "sessions.data", max_epochs, epochs_between_reports, desired_error);
    fann_save(net, "network.net");
    fann_destroy(net);
}
```

What am I missing? It seems so intuitive to me that you could train a network over a span of multiple sessions. Am I wrong? Is it a limitation of the library?

The training data has remained constant between sessions. This isn't limited to this specific network, either -- networks of any format seem to invoke the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What am I missing?*

As per [Documentation - FANN Training > Training Data Manipulation > `fann_set_training_algorithm`](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_set_training_algorithm) :

> Set the [training algorithm](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_train_enum).

Example :

```
fann_set_training_algorithm(net, FANN_TRAIN_INCREMENTAL)
```